# How to react function component in like a toggle button

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want the icon components to change after pressing the Like button, but it doesn't go my way. Would it be possible to get some help?

"Heart"  and "HeartOutline" components call icons.

```
const [heart, setHeartRed] = useState({
    state: false,
    number: '0',
 });

const isLikeyOnHandler = () => {
    heart.state
      ? setHeartRed({ state: false, number: '0' })
      : setHeartRed({ state: true, number: '1' });
  };

return(
    <HeartButton
      text={heart.number}
      icon={heart.state ? <Heart /> : <HeartOutline />}
      onClick={() => isLikeyOnHandler()}
    />
)
```

Comment: *"but it doesn't go my way"* - Could you perhaps be more specific about the problem you're observing?

Comment: `useCallback` and `useEffect` are your friends here.

Comment: I wanted it to change to a "heart component" when the button is clicked. Click again to return to the "outline heart".

Comment: Could you add `HeartButton` implementation to your question

Comment: I wrote the answer below, but it doesn't work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const [heart, setHeartRed] = useState({
    state: false,
    number: '0',
 });

const isLikeyOnHandler = () => {
setHeartRed((prevState)=>({state:!prevState.state,number:+!+prevState.number+""})
  };

return(
    <HeartButton
      text={heart.number}
      icon={heart.state ? <Heart /> : <HeartOutline />}
      onClick={isLikeyOnHandler}
    />
)
```